# how to use subprocess.run to install program

Tags: python-3.x

I need example how to run `subprocess.run` to install program such as notepad++ in silent mode.

I'm using following code

```
iv_arg = [r'C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Utilities_Installers_new\Programs\npp.7.5.4.Installer.exe']
       subprocess.run(iv_arg)
```

Comment: I suppose you need to run as admin or that won't work

Comment: And what's going wrong? Do you get error messages?

Comment: I need to know how to make it silent install

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I install msi packages using `subprocess.run()`:

```
installOutput = subprocess.run(["msiexec", "/i", 
                                fullPathToMSIFile, 
                                "/lv", logfile, 
                                "/quiet", 
                                "/norestart"], 
                               capture_output=True, 
                               text=True)
```

`/i` - install

`/lv` - verbose log of the installation into the specified `logfile`

`/quiet` - doesn't show any UI

`/norestart` - only installs and doesn't restart the machine

`capture_output = True` - captures the `stdout` and `stderr` streams

`text = True` - captures `stdout` and `stderr` as text instead of as binary streams

So you can download the MSI package for notepad++ and install it using the above snippet.